# Rails 4 joins query display the wrong resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have 2 resources, doctors and reservations.

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reservations
end

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :doctor
end
```

**Schema:**

```
  create_table "reservations", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "doctor_id"
    t.date     "date"
  end

 create_table "doctors", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

I want to display all the doctors available on a date, so all the doctors that dont have any reservations on that day.

**My query:**

```
  def index
    @doctors = Doctor.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @doctors = @doctors.joins(:reservations).where.not('reservations.date LIKE ?',params[:free_on]) if params[:free_on].present?
    @doctors = @doctors.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
  end
```

My problem is:
That query gives me the reservations as a result.
If a I have 1 doctor and 3 reservations in my database, and I select the 1st of november (1 reservation on that date), it shows me 2 times the same doctor, for the 2 reservations that are not on the 1st november.

I tried .group, but again it shows me only 1 doctors if there is a reservation...

Someone has an idea of whats wrong with my query ?

Thank you,

Comment: try includes instead of joins? typically you should probably prefer includes over joins...

Comment: Thx for your help but same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire premise of your query is wrong.

```
@doctors = @doctors.joins(:reservations).where.not('reservations.date LIKE ?',params[:free_on])
```

You're finding doctors that have reservations on days other than the "free_on" - regardless of whether they have a reservation on "free_on".  That's not what you want to do.  You want to find doctors who have no reservations on "free_on".

```
@doctors = @doctors.where("not exists (select * from reservations where doctor_id=doctors.id and reservations.date=?)", params[:free_on])
```

That should be optimizable to use indices and run pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `uniq`?

```
@doctors = @doctors.joins(:reservations).where.not('reservations.date LIKE ?',params[:free_on]).uniq
```

As a sidenote, I would be concerned with using `.date LIKE ?` for such a functionality.

Comment: Thank for you help.
With .uniq it gives me one result instead of 3 but the problem remains the same. I think my query is not correct.
For your sidenote, what would you use ? (i'm learning)